# JFreeChart different fonts or font sizes in title

Tags: jfreechart

Is it possible to use different fonts or font sizes in the title of a `JFreeChart` object?

Using:

```
chart.getTitle().setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
```

allows one to set the font but I am trying to create a bold, large font-size title followed by an explanatory sub-title with smaller font size on the line below.

E.g. something like: "Intensive Care Infections / data from 2008-01-01 up to 2012-12-31"

Any other way to achieve this effect, if not possible in the `title` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add one or many subtitles using the [addSubtitle()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html#addSubtitle%28int,%20org.jfree.chart.title.Title%29) method in the JFreeChart class.  The title is always drawn first, then the subtitles are drawn (by index order).  Note that the legend is added to the chart as a "subtitle", so depending on the position you may want to insert your real subtitle at index 0 so that it is positioned and drawn before the legend.